# Override New button of Case is not effecting in Lightning Service Console

Tags: service-cloud-console, service

Overriding New standard button of Case object with a Visualforce page. On landing VF page we are checking 2 recordtypes :

1. If RT 1 then launch a New Case Create Lightning App
2. If RT 2 then redirect to standard pagelayout

Its working fine in Classic and lightinig mode both.

But when we create a Lightning app for console and click on New button
of listview its opening recordtype selection standard page.

After selection of recordType its opening 2 tabs for case creation
with standard page layouts. Not landing VF page on selection of RT1.

Seems Standard button override navigation does not work as expected in lightining console App. does it?

Please let me know if any workarround of it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to be possible. [Earlier versions of the documentation explicitly make reference to this limitation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_lex_s1_action_overrides_basics.htm), but [later versions do not have it in this section](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_lex_s1_action_overrides_basics.htm). It can be found in [this area](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=console_lex_limitations.htm&type=5), though.

[There is an idea for it here, though](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lJNaQAM).

I've not found a workaround for it yet.